# Project not found in java ee file

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I've downloaded a file from github(cloned it as well as downloaded it as a zip).
Here is the adress: https://github.com/bargenson/RMT .

I would like to open it to work with it and understand how the author used jsf, validation beans since I have some homework to do.

But my Netbeans (IDE 8.0.2) won't find any project in that file.
So I can't run it and debug it.

EDIT : After unzipping the file, I can't find any project to open in my IDE:

[image]

Can you guys help me understand how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a netbeans project? Maybe it was developed with another IDE, such as Eclipse or Intellij?

Comment: It was indeed created with IntelliJ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project you linked does not provide the metadata of a netbeans project¹. That means that either the original developer did use some different IDE (or no IDE at all) or that he did not choose to include said metadata into the repository.

You should be able to create a new free-form project from the `build.xml` within the project directory (after extracting the archive you downloaded). If you only wish to run specific code, you can also directly build the project from shell using `ant`.

---

¹ NetBeans uses a `nbproject` folder within each project's directory to track NetBeans-specific information, such as the mapping of the IDE's run and debug button to actual features of the project.

Comment: I love you!
Is it possible to make that free-form project run?
Once again thank you!

Comment: I have never worked with Java EE. Judging from the `build.xml`, you should use "all" as target for build and there is no intended way to run your project via ant. It looks to me as if you'd need to deploy the compiled stuff to a server, not sure about debugging and similar stuff. If you know how to deploy EE projects via `ant` to a server of your choice, you can add that code to the `build.xml` and link it to the run action of the IDE. If you don't, I'd suggest searching for "java ee ant run" or similar, [this seems to be an example](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipob.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to unzip it.  That should work.

Comment: Did it work for you? I can't find any project when I unzip the file!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, I've finally found out that you can run this kind of project by creating a new project "with existing sources".
It worked perfectyl :)